# How to deny a role / user access to all Controllers / Actions apart from specified exceptions asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, roles

I would like to be able to specify either a role a user that isn't allowed to access and entire site when all other users are.

I would then like to be able to do something along the lines of an authorize header on selected actions so that the denied user is still allowed access this selected action and controller if possible.

I know I could create a role, add all other users to this role and then do an authorization attribute on this role but this would have to be done on every single action which is a non-starter because the project is already built with hundreds if not thousands of actions.

So any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: Security isn't easy.  If you built it without security in mind, and created "thousands" of actions, you have a lot of work ahead of you regardless of whatever solution you use.  So immediately dismissing something as too much work will result in not enough security.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch It's currently secured where it needs to be using Authorise, but this does not give me the ability to block one user or role from what I can gather. If there is a solution I can implement into authorise however I will be more than happy to give it a shot!

Comment: There is no "Deny" functionality in AuthorizeAttribute, only Allow.  If you want to use standard Authorization, you need to make your roles more granular and only assign the roles that a user has access to.  In general, especially when you have "thousands" of actions and many users, it's not maintainable to allow or deny users specifically on actions.  You would probably have to build some kind of data driven access otherwise, which is not trivial.  Also, much depends on which exact versions of mvc you're using, and which exact forms of authentication/authorization you're using.

Comment: For instance, your question is tagged with asp-net-membership, but are you in fact using Membership?  Or are you using asp.net Identity?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch the project is using membership for its roles system. This is why I'm wondering if it would be possible to use a role as this would allow users to be denied using a role. I may have to instead do it the opposite way round where every user is in a role apart from the one I want to deny. This needs to be done because I would like to let users collectively use this user to access secure sections of the system where email links with security guid in will be providing the security. But I don't want this user account to be able to access any of the usual account editing things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution here would probably be a custom Authorize attribute to add Deny functionality.  You could implement this in a number of ways.  For instance, you could deny based on a specific role, but that can be difficult to maintain over time if you want to deny people from different parts of the app, you'd have to create different roles and change your code every time you want to do that.

For example:

```
public class DenyAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute 
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        return !base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }
}
```

This uses the Roles property of the AuthorizeAttribute as a deny.

```
[Deny(Roles="DeniedUsers")]
```

Be aware though, that you would need some kind of higher level authorization, such as at the Controller or global filter level that blocks overall unauthenticated users, otherwise it would allow anyone not in the Role specified to have access, including unauthenticated users.  So maybe add something like:

```
return httpContext.User.IsAuthenticated && !base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
```

Also be aware that using this in conjunction with an `[AllowAnonymous]` might be problematic.

Another option would be to create a more flexible system that would calculate the deny based on the current controller/action.  Something like this:

```
public class DenyByControllerActionAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var controller = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        var action = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
        var denyRole = string.Format("Deny{0}:{1}", controller, action);
        return !httpContext.User.IsInRole(denyRole) && base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }
}
```

Which you can then control access by adding the user to a role of the format "Deny{Controller}:{Action}", so something like DenyHome:Index or "DenyAdmin:Email".

This will also require they have Default authorize access as well by calling the base AuthorizeCore functionality.  So, you can do a wholesale replace of `[Authorize]` with `[DenyByControllerAction] and it will work the same way (or use it as a global filter), but simply adding the role you can deny any user access to any Controller/Action.

Comment: The deny one will work for my purposes, thanks for the help!

Comment: @jjr2000 - Just keep in mind the caveat's I mentioned.  You may need to do some extensive testing in your environment to ensure you're security is what you expect it to be.