# Temporary Block REST-Controllers

Tags: c#, rest, iis, asp.net-web-api

In our Application we communicate with an IIS-Service over REST. All controller-classes are decorated with the `Authorize` attribute like:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "CompApi-User, CompApi-Administration")]
public class ComponentsController : ApiController
{ ... }
```

Now we want to implement a mechanis to temporary block all users which are in the "CompApi-User"-Role to all controllers.

Is there a default-behaviour which we can use, or do have to check this in each controller?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken there are couples of the way to do it but I'm not sure if this is applicable to your needs. You can deny or allow user by role via config `<authorization>
  <allow roles="CompApi-Administration"/>
  <deny users="CompApi-User" />
</authorization>`

or by extending `AuthorizationFilterAttributte` and register `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new YourExtendedAuthorization)`.

Comment: By adding a declarative Role  "CompApi-User" I would say that you defined that this function is ALWAYS ALLOWED for users in that group. Generally speaking then, you should remove these roles temporarily from all of the users that currently have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now we want to implement a mechanism to **temporary block all users which
>   are in the "CompApi-User" Role to all controllers.**

So every time that you need it, you don't want a new deployment. You just want to change a config.

You also want it for all controllers, it means you need something like a global action filter.

And the last point, you probably know well, but it's worth to mention, deny is not equal to removing the role from allowed roles. It means you should deny access, if the user is in a specific role, regardless of the other roles which they have and may be granted to access.

Here is the attribute:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
public class DenyAccessAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext == null)
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(actionContext));
        if (!IsAuthorized(actionContext))
            HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
    }
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var user = actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal;
        if (!(user == null || user.Identity == null))
        {
            var roles = GetDeniedRoles();
            if (roles != null && roles.Count() > 0 && roles.Any(user.IsInRole))
                return false;
        }
        return base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);
    }
    public virtual IEnumerable<string> GetDeniedRoles()
    {
        var config = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
            .AppSettings["DeniedRoles"];
        var roles = config?.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim())
            .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
        return roles;
    }
}
```

Just register it in `Register` method of `WebApiConfig`:

```
config.Filters.Add(new DenyAccessAttribute());
```

Then every time that you want to deny a role, as soon as you add it to the `DeniedRoles` in appsettings, the access for the role will be denied to all controllers:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="DeniedRoles" value="Admin,PowerUser"/>
<appSettings>
```

**Note:**

- It's denying all the roles which you specify in `DeniedRoles` in `appsettings`, regardless of their granted access.
- It also denies them from accessing all the controllers, regardless of any allow anonymous. If you like to keep allow anonymous as it was, just comment `OnAuthorization` to use the default behavior.
- If you want further customization, take a look at source code of [AuthorizeAttribute.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/AuthorizeAttribute.cs) on GitHub.
- You don't necessarily need to derive from `AuthorizeAttribute`, you can also derive from `AuthorizationFilterAttribute`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no build-in or  default-behaviour to temporary  block all users which are in the "CompApi-User"-Role to all controllers.

To achvie this thing, you need to write the codes by yourself. You need to create custom Authorize attribute to add Deny functionality. Then you should add it to each controller.

In the deny function, you could write the codes to deny the role according to web.config setting to achieve temporary  block.

More details about how to create a custom Authorize attribute , you could refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44010335/7609093).

Answer (score 0):

If you are blocking access to a whole range of controllers actions temporarily, and if you are using IIS to run the website, then you could redirect all of those methods easily by using HTTP Redirection module in IIS - just add rules to web.config and divert users to a 404 page (or code up a 401/403 page). Once you are done, just comment out those rules (so that you can edit/reuse later).

Comment: They want to disable access for specific roles. Not all roles.